# Using gsub to extract the a code (numbers and characters)

Tags: r

I have a string and I wish to extract the code but I'm not quite able to re-create it, the code will change each time but the IDs part will always be the same

mycode
"IDs/5362E-C3A~16DFR-54RFFG"

What I'm looking to get;

```
mycode
"5362E-C3A"
```

My attempt, I tried to break it down into 3 parts, Ids, the code I need and the tilde and other waste bit of code then saying I want to keep the first instance inside of the brackets.

```
mycode = gsub("IDs/([A-9]+)~[A-9+]", "\\1", mycode)
```

Comment: Your character ranges seem off because the digits are before the capital letters and you aren't matching the dash itself. Maybe you meant `gsub("IDs/([A-Z0-9-]+)~[A-Z0-9-]+", "\\1", mycode)`

Comment: `sub(".*/(.*)~.*", "\\1", mycode)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want everything in between the `/` and the `~`, you could try the following regex replacement which uses an alternation:

```r
x <- "IDs/5362E-C3A~16DFR-54RFFG"
output <- gsub(".*/|~.*", "", x)
output

[1] "5362E-C3A"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining your splitting in the "IDs/" part and the tilde part, you could use this regex which replaces the first chars and the whole substring after the tilde, using nested gsubs

```
mycode = "IDs/5362E-C3A~16DFR-54RFFG"
gsub("IDs/", '', gsub("~[^~]*$", '', mycode))
```